# Force Next.js 13.4 App Router to update list

Tags: next.js

I'm currently migrating my dashboard to Next.js 13.4 App Router. Within the dashboard, I have multiple pages that consume data from an external API for listing data from a database and performing CRUD actions.

One challenge I'm facing is that the lists remain cached unless I manually refresh the page. Even when I navigate between different pages, the lists do not update automatically.

Although this caching behavior enhances app performance, it's not very practical in my case. I need a solution that allows the lists to update either when I navigate between pages or by triggering specific commands.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```js
export default async function Page() {
  async function getData() {
    const getData = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/v1/report", {
      headers: {
        "x-access-token": "token",
      },
    });
    return await getData.json();
  }

  const data = await getData();
}

return <div>list here...</div>;
```

I tried to use `export const revalidate = 2`

And:

```js
fetch('https://...', { next: { revalidate: 2 } })
```

They doesn't work.

It would be great if I could automatically update the list whenever a user performs an action. If that's not possible, I would need to refresh the list every time the user navigates to that particular route, even if the page hasn't been reloaded.